# Spring + Hibernate org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Tying to set up my 1st Spring4.2.5 + Hibernate4.3.11 project

I think i just need a fresh pair of eyes to see what is wrong with my setup.  I pretty much follow the docs and other tutorials step by step.  Thanks in advance.

When I compile i get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.app.books.BookDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy
```

At the bottom of the stack the cause is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy
```

I pretty much checked everything I don't know what is causing Class not found below are my codes.

dependency

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Web.xml

```
  <!-- Dispatcher Servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>app-dispatcher</display-name>
    <servlet-name>app-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Context Listener -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:com/app/config/dao-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
```

dao-context.xml

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app"></context:component-scan>
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Spring Hibernate Set up 
         http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"></property>
        <property name="username" value="xxxxx"></property>
        <property name="password" value="xxxxx"></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>

        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.app.books</value>
                </list>
            </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslator"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

BookDao

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Component("bookDao")
public class BookDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session session(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    // Get all list of books
    public List<Book> getBookList(){

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Book> returnObj = session().createQuery("from Book").list();

        return returnObj;
    }

}
```

Book

```
@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Book{

    /**
     * 
     */
    //private static final long serialVersionUID = -2042607611480064259L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String ispn;
    private double price;

    public Book(){}

    public Book(String name, String ispn, double price){
        this.name = name;
        this.ispn = ispn;
        this.price = price;
    }

    getter & setters methods...
```

Thank you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mostly copy and paste the session factory config and didn´t notice the hibernate 5 reference.

```
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
```

Better move to Hibernate 5.

Comment: OHHH thanks for pointing this out.... I remember now I had hibernate 5 before but it was giving me java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;  I than searched around and people say spring 4.26 is not compatible with hibernate 5.1  I can move to 5 but do you have a solution to this problem?  thx

Comment: Sorry, no I don't. If I'm not wrong, Spring supports Hibernate 5 in version 4.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this **dao-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="xxx" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="xxx" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.app.Book</beans:value><!-- Models -->
<!--    <beans:value>com.com.app.Author
            </beans:value> -->
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.books" />

<beans:bean id="bookDaoImpl" class="com.app.BookDaoImpl" /><!--daoImpl classes -->
<beans:bean id="bookServiceImpl" class="com.app.BookServiceImpl" /><!--serviceImpl classes -->
```